# Multiple models and uploading files

Tags: file, upload, yii, models

At first - I'm new to the Yii Framework. I did some research on my own but I couldn't find a precise solution to my issue.

Assume there are two related models - Product and Image. A single Product may have multiple Images assigned. What is the best approach at creating the create / update forms that would be able to manage this kind of scheme?

The Image model consists of various fields, along with a path to the image file, so it's not just a "container" for the path itself. What's more - I need to have a thumbnail generated for every uploaded image and its path stored within the same model.

What I need to achieve is pretty much similar to the admin inline functionality known from Django - there should be a section in the Product create / update form which would allow users to add / modify / delete Images.

I tried the multimodelform extension but I couldn't get file uploading to work. What's the best way of getting it done and not having to build the whole file-upload-enabled-multiple-model-form structure manually?

Comment: For multiple image upload use this extension.

 http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/ 

For creating thumbnail...

  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simpleimage/

Answer (score 0):

The detailed solution depends on if you are using CActiveForm or CHtml form. Since you have 2 related models I assume you are using CActiveForm and will point out some thing you need to keep in mind.

For this example i am gonna assume some definitions 
Product with fields id, name
Product with ONE to MANY relation to 'images' on ProductImage
ProductImage with fields id, productId, path

I also assume there gonna be 1 upload / edit, but multi delete

Here's the view:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )
);

echo $form->labelEx($product, 'name');
echo $form->fileField($product, 'name');
echo $form->error($product, 'name');

echo $form->checkBoxList($product, 'path', $product->images);


echo $form->labelEx($productImage, 'path');
echo $form->fileField($productImage, 'path');
echo $form->error($productImage, 'path');


$this->endWidget();
```

And your action

```
public function actionUpdate($productId) {

    $product = Product::model()->findByPk($productId)->with('images');
    $productImage = new ProductImage();

    if(isset($_POST['Item']))
    {
        $product->attributes=$_POST['Product'];

        foreach($product->images as $im) {
            if(in_array($im->path, $_POST['Item']['Image']))
                $im->delete();
        }
        $productImage->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($productImage,'path');
        if($productImage->save())
        {
            $productImage->image->saveAs('some/new/path');
            // redirect to success page
        }
    }
    $this->render('update', array(
            'product'=>$product,
            'productImage'=>$productImage,
        ));
}
```

Now note that this solution is not tested so there will be bugs, but it should give you an idea on how to write your own form.

Resources:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/384/creating-and-updating-model-and-its-related-models-in-one-form-inc-image